# ip_conntrack and FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, pf, tcp-ip, ip-conntrack

We can figure out number of connections in GNU\Linux with ip_conntrack module, And I can print current connections and maximum of connections with:

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen/test/shell# sysctl net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_count
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_count = 28
root@debian:/home/mohsen/test/shell# sysctl net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max 
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 65536
```

And i can change them.

And with PF firewall i can :

```
pfctl -si | grep current
pfctl -sm | grep states
```

Now, I have two serious question:

1. How can I change them in PF firewall?
2. How can I change maximum and current such as ip_conntrack in FreeBSD without any firewall or thirdparty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set options in pfctl.conf with a `set limit { ... }` statement.

You can modify the packet filter state while it is running by passing the `-m' (merge) option to pfctl(8), ie

```
    FreeBSD 9.3-RELEASE-p10 (GENERIC) #0: Tue Feb 24 21:28:03 UTC 2015
    # pfctl -sm
    No ALTQ support in kernel
    ALTQ related functions disabled
    states        hard limit    10000
    src-nodes     hard limit    10000
    frags         hard limit     5000
    tables        hard limit     1000
    table-entries hard limit   200000
    # echo "set limit { states 1000000, frags 1000000, src-nodes 100000, tables 1000000, table-entries 1000000 }" | pfctl -mf -
    No ALTQ support in kernel
    ALTQ related functions disabled
    # pfctl -sm
    No ALTQ support in kernel
    ALTQ related functions disabled
    states        hard limit  1000000
    src-nodes     hard limit   100000
    frags         hard limit  1000000
    tables        hard limit  1000000
    table-entries hard limit  1000000
```